# Single post - display list of all posts + specific post

Tags: wp-query

I want to display on single post three things:

- List of all posts in general
- Single post title
- Content

What I achieved right now is not satisfying because I am displaying all posts (and it works ok) but the second part (connected with showing only specific post title and content) don't work because it shows only the newest one.

For example:

I have 2 posts called "News about IT" and "TV series". Post about TV is the newest one. After clicking on News about IT i will see all posts in the top and as a main part - title and content of NEWS ABOUT IT. Right now using my solution it shows TV series as a newest post..

How can I achieve my solution?

This is my current code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="center">
        <div class="sub-menu-1">
            <a href="#" title="O nas" class="about-us"> O nas </a>
            <a href="#" title="Oferta" class="offer"> Oferta</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="news-slider">
            <a href="#" title="Nowsze wpisy" class="arrow-left" id="mycarousel-prev"></a>

            <div class="news-content">

                <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                    <?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></p>
                            <p class="separator"></p>
                            <p class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                                                     title="<?php printf(esc_attr__('Odsyłacz do %s', 'sp3-rybnik'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"
                                                     rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        </li>

                    <?php endwhile;
                    else: ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        <h4>404 - brak strony...</h4>
                        <p>Wielka otchłań internetu połknęła wskazaną stronę - wyszukaj interesującą Cię treść
                            korzystając z
                            menu.</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <a href="#" title="Starsze wpisy" class="arrow-right" id="mycarousel-next"></a>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="content-single">
    <div class="content-single-entry">
        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        <?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :
        the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p class="separator"></p>
        <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></p>


        <div id="scrollbar1">
            <div class="scrollbar">
                <div class="track">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <div class="end"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="viewport">
                <div class="overview">

                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php endwhile;
                    else: ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        <h4>404 -brak strony...</h4>
                        <p>Wielka otchłań internetu połknęła wskazaną stronę - wyszukaj interesującą Cię treść
                            korzystając z menu.</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. If that pastebin links breaks the question become meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

When the single post template is loaded, WordPress has already queried the database for that post. When you call `query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=1');`, and then run the loop, this simply loads and outputs a single post, which by default will be the latest post. It also has the side-effect of overwriting the original main query.

You don't need to, nor should you ever call `query_posts` in the template.

To load additional posts beside the single post you are currently viewing, **use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**, and leave the main query unaltered.

```
// load and display all posts
// setting post_type is unnecessary, it will default to post
$all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
while( $all_posts->have_posts() ):
    $all_posts->the_post();
    // your markup for all posts
endwhile;

// reset the global post variable
wp_reset_postdata();

// now output the single post
// no need for a query, the post data already exists
// in the global $wp_query
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();
    // your markup for the single post
endwhile;
```